# Reassign application configuration to another package

Tags: package, abap

We accidentally assign a `Web Dynpro` application configuration to package `$tmp`.

We couldn't find a way to reassign it to a transportable package.

We tried via `SE80` → `Repository Browser` → `Web Dynpro Comp. / Intf.` → `Web Dynpro Applications` → `<our application>` → `Applc. Configurations` → `<our application configuration>` → `<right click>`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can change package assignments in transaction SE03:

Start the transacation
Select: Object Directory => Change Object Directory Entries

In the selection criteria, you have to add `R3TR` / `WDYN` / *`name of the WebDynpro object`*
(* actually you cannot enter `R3TR` manually, you have to select it)
Click on Execute.

Double click the `R3TR` / `WDYN` / *`WebDynpro object`* line, a popup will appear, where you can change the package assignment.

Comment: Instead of transaction `SE03` → `Object Directory` → `Change Object Directory Entries`, another way to the same place is via transaction `SM30` → `TADIR`.